# Excel formula for value from cell to the left of a cell referenced by a dynamically generated value

Tags: excel, error-handling, vlookup, offset

**Edited problem:**

I have an Excel spreadsheet I'm trying to set up where users can calculate the time they spend on different projects each month, the sheet calculating their monthly totals and automatically completing their timesheet. There is a configuration page where users enter their details and details of the projects they work on in a table set up as below:

[image: Configuration showing projects and categories]

(**EDIT**: In my original table the project category was in column A, and the project name was in column B, but I switched them round so that `=VLOOKUP` will work)

The calculation sheet allows users to select any of the projects they've listed on the configuration page using a drop-down list to a maximum of 15 projects, the source of which is the table on the configuration page. Part of the time calculation sheet shown below:

[image: Project times calculation sheet]

The final part of it is the page that displays the timesheet, which pulls the project names from the calculation sheet. So that users can enter notes regarding the projects, under the calculation table is another table which lists the column headings, the project names, vertically to allow them to enter further information. It's this list on the calculation page that is the source of the project names on the timesheet page for each month, so the cells on the timesheet page use `='Period 1'!A37`, `='Period 1'!A38`, `='Period 1'!A39` etc. to get the project names. The second table on the calculation page is shown below:

[image: table to add notes to projects]

It's all working fine, except I'm planning eventually to set it up so that each user's data is pulled from their copy of the timesheet system into a single spreadsheet to save me a week's worth of inputting - that's a whole different ballgame and something for the future though because my knowledge of Excel currently isn't up to figuring out how to do that without learning more about Excel's functions. What I have realised though is that I'm going to need to pull off the project's category as well as its name from the timesheet page for when I come to do the analysis of it, and it's this that's causing me problems.

This is my final page, the timesheet for each month (**edit**: I've added an additional column which I'll hide as it's not needed on the timesheet the user sees, to hold the project category):

[image: timesheet table displaying users projects and total times]

**EDIT - PARTIAL SOLUTION:**

When I looked at it again and tried the `=VLOOKUP` function again, I realised that I was making things far more complicated than they needed to be thinking that I needed to use `=VLOOKUP` and `=OFFSET` to find the project category. `=OFFSET` isn't required as I thought it might be to chose the value in the cell to the left of the project name. By switching round the columns in the table on the configuration page I realised I could simply use `=VLOOKUP` to find the project name's category, e.g. `=VLOOKUP(A16,Configuration!B25:F54,2,FALSE)`
and it's working as long as there is a result for each row on timesheet, but where the user selects less than 15 projects and `=VLOOKUP` doesn't return a value, it's displaying #N/A. I've tried a couple of things to try and get rid of that, but neither are working and simply enter FALSE even if there is a value to return from `=VLOOKUP`, so it's almost working, but not quite, as I can't quite figure out how to get rid of the #N/A without it messing up the `=VLOOKUP`.

These are what I've tried:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B16,'Configuration'!B25:F54,2,FALSE),"")

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A16,Configuration!B25:F54,2,FALSE)),0)
```

Both of these display 'FALSE' whether `=VLOOKUP` finds a value or not, so I've just about figured it out except for that final annoying error.

Comment: This question is a bit wordy while showing no data or attempts... can you show us a simplified example with example data and example desired outputs?

Comment: Sorry, yes I do have a tendency to ramble a bit! I've edited my post with examples of the tables. I inadventently discovered a partial solution - well a solution thaat works (it wasn't half as complicated as I thought it'd be) - but the only problem I have now is getting rid of an annoying error displaying.